# I want to hide navigation when I click to anchor element

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have problem with my navigation bar, actually it works pretty well but I don't know how to activate **:active** psydo class for the anchors tag when clicked . So here is my html code and css and the main thing that I want to do...

So this is my html part of navigation

```
<div class="navigation">
      <input type="checkbox" class="navigation__checkbox" id="navi-toggle">

      <label for="navi-toggle" class="navigation__button">
        <span class="navigation__icon">&nbsp;</span>
      </label>

      <div id="background" class="navigation__background">&nbsp;</div>

      <nav class="navigation__nav">
        <ul class="navigation__list">
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link">About Me</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Skills</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#projects" class="navigation__link">Projects</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Contact Me</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#" class="navigation__link">Message Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
```

When I press hamburger button navigation comes up and when I press times(X) navigation closes
Also here is my css(SASS) code

```
.navigation {
  &__checkbox {
    display: none;
  }
  &__button {
    background-color: $color-white;
    height: 7rem;
    width: 7rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 6rem;
    right: 6rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2000;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba($color-black, 0.1);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;

    @include respond(tab-port) {
      top: 4rem;
      right: 4rem;
    }

    @include respond(phone) {
      top: 3rem;
      right: 3rem;
    }
  }

  &__background {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 6.5rem;
    right: 6.5rem;
    background-image: radial-gradient($color-red, $color-black);
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.12, 0.48, 0.49, -0.74);

    @include respond(tab-port) {
      top: 4.5rem;
      right: 4.5rem;
    }
    @include respond(phone) {
      top: 3.5rem;
      right: 3.5rem;
    }
  }

  &__nav {
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1500;

    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(1, -0.69, 0.73, 1.95);
  }

  &__list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__link {
    &:link,
    &:visited {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: $color-white;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background-image: linear-gradient(
        120deg,
        transparent 0%,
        transparent 50%,
        $color-white 50%
      );
      background-size: 230%;
      transition: all 0.4s;
    }

    &:hover {
      background-position: 100%;
      color: $color-black;
      transform: translateX(-1rem);
    }
  }

  &__item {
    margin: 1rem;
  }

  &__checkbox:checked ~ &__background {
    transform: scale(80);
  }

  &__checkbox:checked ~ &__nav {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }

  //Icon
  &__icon {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3.4rem;

    &,
    &::before,
    &::after {
      width: 3rem;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: $color-grey-dark;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    &::before,
    &::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    &::before {
      top: -0.8rem;
    }

    &::after {
      top: 0.8rem;
    }
  }

  &__button:hover &__icon::before {
    top: -1rem;
  }

  &__button:hover &__icon::after {
    top: 1rem;
  }


  &__checkbox:checked + &__button &__icon {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &__checkbox:checked + &__button &__icon::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }

  &__checkbox:checked + &__button &__icon::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }

}
```

So I want the same thing to happen when I press one of the anchors tag , I've tried to do same like here when checkbox is checked to put out of sight.

```
&__checkbox:checked ~ &__background {
    transform: scale(80);
  }

  &__checkbox:checked ~ &__nav {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

As I said I've tried to do something like this but it didn't work, so do you have any idea how can I do that ? Thanks in advance.

```
&__link:active ~ &__background{
transform scale(1)
}

&__link:active ~ &__nav {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
```

[hamburger button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hwDd.jpg)

[navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao9jn.jpg)

So when I click hamburger button, navigation comes up and when I click it again it closes. I want to do the same for anchor tags, so when I click one of the anchor tags menu should close. Here is my webpage so you can analyze better [www.erolramacik.com](https://www.erolramacik.com)

Comment: try adding a snippet that represents the problem you are facing

Comment: I added snipets and also webpage so you can understand better what I want. Just open the navigation and you will see anchor tagsof there but I couldn't make that menu disappers when I click on anchor tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with simple vanilla js

1) select all your menu links

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__link');
```

2) add listener for click, and set checkbox check state to false when it happen

```
links.forEach(link => { 
   link.addEventListener("click", () => { 
     document.querySelector('.navigation__checkbox').checked = false
   })
})
```

Comment: I actually want to do with scss and not with js, I did it with JS but now I want to do it with SASS. Anyway thanks

Comment: Your code will not work as ~ means siblings, and __background and __nav are not siblings of your links but parents. As I know there is no way to select parent element with css

Comment: It's actually easier with JS as you described but I wanted just to challenge myself. anyway thanks a lot